# How to save storage in python crawler (common strings)

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, web-crawler

I have a python3 crawler that connect to target sites and saves all html and resources. Although I compress with gzip before saving it consumes too much space and I usually reach my configured space limit before less than half of website pages are crawled.

The point is that all pages of the same website have a lot of common strings (there are even websites that include resources like css in all html pages instead linking then). Then my idea is saving the common strings for the same website. I thought this kind of optimization would be documented, but I didn't found anything about this.

Although I have this idea, I don't know how to implement this kind of algorithm. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why did you want to get resources like CSS? I mean, the HTML is enough for getting data. I have crawled more than 15K HTML of pages, each HTML page just 100-200KB

Comment: Otherwise, making a checkpoint for crawler is not a bad idea for continuous processing

Comment: @TấnNguyên Usually they aren't heavy, but I have seen some that exceeds 1.5MB. I need css for getting background images mainly which I also want to crawl.

Comment: If you need css just for a few things parsing them out and storing only the relevant bits could help much more than a compression or duplicate matching.

Comment: Did you try `xz` compression?Sometimes it works much better than `gzip`

Comment: when u talk about space, do u mean storage or ram?

Comment: @Marcos storage

Comment: Does any of the proposed solutions solves the problem or something is still missing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common compression algorithms can already save a lot of space on common strings, and this would be a very good case if you have pages from the same website. Instead of saving and compressing the pages individually, try to put similar pages in the same file and compress that. It should make the compression rate much better.

You should try to make the window size of your compression larger than the average page in order to make it utilize the data of previous pages.

If you are saving them to disk or using a database, you can use the domain name or the first X characters of the URL as your index to find the compressed file, so pages under the same domain/directory will naturally get compressed together.

---

Another approach you can take is to create "dictionaries" for your compression. Some compression algorithms allow you to give a few example files to train a dictionary that can then be used to compress similar files better. An example of an algorithm that does this is [zstd](https://github.com/facebook/zstd). You can read how to use the dictionary feature [here](https://github.com/facebook/zstd#dictionary-compression-how-to).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to download all html pages with a single presence of CSS files and zip them together. Something like following zip-file structure:

```
stackoverflow.com.zip
    /home.html
    /questions.html
    /tags.html
    /users.html

    /cdn-static/
        cdn.sstatic.net__Sites__stackoverflow__Img__favicon.ico
        cdn.sstatic.net__Sites__stackoverflow__primary.css
        cdn.sstatic.net__Shared__stacks.css
```

Also you can store parts of pages separately. For example, I believe that most part of HTML `head` is almost the same for all pages and can contain big chunk of inline scripts or inline styles. You can do HTML parsing using `BeautifulSoup4` library and after that compare parts of HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

You can either save only the page < body > or create a specific solution for each website and save only the relevant content.

For both solutions you can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) as your answer,

Here is a short example how to take only the body from a variable containing the page html (not compressed)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Download the page
response = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
variable_with_site_html = response.content
# Choose only the page body
soup = BeautifulSoup(variable_with_site_html, "html.parser")
page_body = soup.body
```